# PostgreSQL calculate monthly rate

Tags: sql, postgresql

I Have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE data 
    (
        Event_Date date,
        approved int, 
        total int
    )
    
    INSERT INTO data (Event_date, approved, total)
    VALUES
        ('20190901', '5', '20'),
        ('20190902', '6', '30'),
        ('20190903', '4', '50'),
        ('20190904', '7', '40'),
        ('20190905', '8', '50'),
        ('20190906', '10', '70'),
        ('20190907', '4', '25')
```

How to make a loop or something else for calculate monthly rate from selected month start day until month end day and get results(in  monthly rate  I write how formula need to be use)  like this:

```
Event_date   approved,      total    Rolling monthly rate
------------------------------------------------------------
20190901           5           20           5/20
20190902           6           30           5+6/20+30
20190903           4           50           5+6+4/20+30+50
20190904           7           40           5+6+4+7/20+30+50+40
20190905           8           50           5+6+4+7+8/20+30+50+40+50
20190906           10          70           ....
20190907           4           25           .....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) for that:

```
select event_date, approved, total, 
       sum(approved::numeric) over (order by event_date) / sum(total::numeric) over (order by event_date) as rolling_monthly
from data
order by event_date;
```

Or a bit shorter by using a single window definition:

```
select event_date, approved, total, 
       sum(approved::numeric) over w / sum(total::numeric) over w as rolling_monthly
from data
window w as (order by event_date)
order by event_date;
```

The cast to `::numeric` is necessary because otherwise Postgres would do integer division (and then `5/20` yields `0`)

Comment: what mean `over w ` ?

Comment: It's the same as the `over (....)` in the first query, it just re-uses the window definition which is declared after the FROM